# Cancel Image not showing in uploadify

Tags: javascript, php, html, uploadify

can anyone tell me why my uploadify event is not showing cancel image?

my code is:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <?php $timestamp = time();?>
    $(function() {
        $('#file_upload').uploadify({
            'formData'     : {
                'timestamp' : '<?php echo $timestamp;?>',
                'token'     : '<?php echo md5('unique_salt'.$timestamp);?>'
            },
            'swf'      : 'uploadify.swf',
            'cancelImg' : 'uploadify-cancel.png',
            'folder' : 'uploads',
            'uploader' : 'uploadify.php',
            'displayData'   : 'speed',
            'buttonImg' : 'uploadify-cancel.png',
            'removeCompleted'   : true,
            'auto' : true
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: you can check chrome's Developer Tools -> Network to see if `uploadify-cancel.png` is loading correctly. It might need to be loaded from a different path like `images/uploadify-cancel.png`

Comment: i checked and the image is loading correctly. i dont know what the problem is.

Comment: You can try the suggestion in this other stackoverflow question regarding uploadify http://stackoverflow.com/a/16772793/734366

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved when i edited the image location in CSS page of uploadify and gave the correct path of the "uploadify-cancel.png" and it worked.

Comment: i was facing the same problem thanks for the answer, +1 for this